# Why does my android app crash after adding a sound using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, android-activity, crash

I have been following this video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zGS_zrL0rY&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=17) to add sound to a 5 second splash activity(?) that occurs when the app starts up. Prior to editing the app with the new sound additions detailed in the video the app was working perfectly fine and displaying the image stored in the R.layout.splash xml file

My app was working and the code was pretty much exactly the same as the code in the video at the start. However, after following this video and making the advised changes, the app crashes before showing either the image or sound (no significant information given in any error messages, just that the app has crashed).

I did clean the project again after adding the audio file. 
The audio file does exist in the res/raw folder as pikachu.mp3 (It is a short 3 second sound).
I also tried to run the app without the onPause part of the code but it would still crash instantly.  The code I am running is below, I would be grateful if you could have a look and give me some advice for why the app keeps crashing. Thank you.

```
package com.example.thenewbonston;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

MediaPlayer ourSong;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle TravisLoveBacon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(TravisLoveBacon);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.pikachu);
    ourSong.start();
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new       Intent("com.example.thenewbonston.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
}


}
```

Comment: what does the stacktrace say

Comment: what is the stacktrace?

Comment: Assuming it's the series of messages down the bottom of eclipse, this is what I have:

[2014-07-07 18:02:57 - The New Bonston] Installing The New Bonston.apk...
[2014-07-07 18:03:02 - The New Bonston] Success!
[2014-07-07 18:03:02 - The New Bonston] Starting activity com.example.thenewbonston.Splash on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-07 18:03:04 - The New Bonston] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.thenewbonston/.Splash }

Comment: it tells you what the problem is, without that we cannot help you

Comment: I'm looking up how to get this stack trace, will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: See what the LogCat output says. That will normally provide you a meaningful exception with details that should explain the problem.

Comment: I think I have found what we're looking for, is this the part of logcat that will help? There is a lot of red text so I am not sure. 07-07 10:03:06.098: E/MediaPlayer(751): error (1, -2147483648)

Answer (score 0):

may be you just need clean and built your app , you code looks fine
(Project > Clean in Eclipse )

Comment: No sorry, cleaning didn't help. I did try it before posting.

Thank you for your time though!

Comment: I saw in the video that next to his mp3 file there is a musical note icon. When I look at my file it just have a normal text document looking symbol; do you think this is related? Maybe the mp3 file is not being recognised?

Comment: sir we need see you error stack better than guessing , its may be the file format not supported

Comment: what is the error stack? Where can I find it on the eclipse interface?

Comment: choose DDMS(if you dont find it open window ---> open perspective -->> DDMS ) choose log cat (if you dont find it window ---> show view --> Log cat), error stack the block of code in red line

Comment: i think i find the problem after period you should move to anther view Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(this , antheractivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);

Comment: The LogCat is filled with red lines but I think the most significant is this one: 07-07 10:03:06.098: E/MediaPlayer(751): error (1, -2147483648)

Comment: But without any of the lines involving 'MediaPlayer' the app works fine and displays an image as the background, I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: remove any pic you add , may be this the problem , big letter in images cause problem

Comment: The app runs perfectly without the audio, it's just the addition of audio that stops it from working.

Comment: Sir did you check your intent ,                 Intent openStartingPoint = new       Intent("com.example.thenewbonston.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);    should be   Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(this , new_acticity.class);
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);

Comment: no I did not check that because the app will run fine with the above code if you do not include any lines with "MediaPlayer"